# How to destroy "dynamic lightgallery" instance so that none of its reference appear on another angular component

Tags: angular, lightgallery

I am using angular 6 with laravel 5.2 as backend.

I have two angular component which is using lightGallery [this one](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/dynamic.html) :

- componentOne
- componentTwo

In lightgallery there is option to hit like for the current zoomed image, When we are on **componentOne** and hit like button, it inserts the "db table" image like's data correctly, but when we navigate to **componentTwo** and hit like on image, then it records **two entry**, One entry belongs to componentOne and other entry of componentTwo

In short, componentTwo also records the componentOne like data.

I want to clear all the lightgallery data on ngDestroy() so that it doesn't interfere on componentTwo.

Both the component's codes are same. I am sharing one component's lightgallery code.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../../../../environments/environment';

declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-album-details',
  templateUrl: './album-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./album-details.component.css']
})

export class AlbumDetailsComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {

 constructor() {
        
 }

  ngAfterViewInit(){ 
       // Having list of images
       let details = {type:'paid'};
       this.editAlbumFn("album_list", details);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log('destroy album details');    
    // Can destroy lightgallery here
  }

editAlbumFn(url, object) {
this.requestService.postMethod(url,object) 
    .subscribe(
        (data : any) => {
            if (data.success == true) {
              this.albums = data.data[0];
              this.album_details = data.data;
              console.log(this.album_details);

             // It filters our image data for the dynamic lightgallery
              this.galleryImages = this.album_details.map(item => {
                const images = {};
                images['item_id']  = item.item_id;
                images['subHtml']  = "<div class='fb-comments'></div>";

                if(item.type=='VIDEO') {
                  images['thumb']    = '/assets/img/video-icon.png';
                  images['html'] = '<video class="lg-video-object lg-html5" controls preload="none"><source src="'+item.video+'" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video</video>'
                } else {
                  images['src']      = item.photo;
                  images['thumb']    = item.thumb;
                }

                return images;
              })

             // Help to initialize the lightgallery
              this.activateLightbox(this.galleryImages, this.model_id);

            } else {
                this.toast_message("Error", data.error_messages);                    
            }
        },

        (err : HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.errorMessages = 'Oops! Something Went Wrong';
            this.toast_message("Error", this.errorMessages);
        }
    );
}

activateLightbox(galleryImages: any, model_id) {

    var galleryImag =  galleryImages;
    var user_id, post_id;

    setTimeout(() => {

    
        // each .item class is a bootstrap grid  
        var $commentBox = $(".item");
               
        $commentBox.on('click', function (e) {

         // Used this to destroy the previous component lightgallery data
          if($(this).data('lightGallery')) {
            console.log('destroy');            
            $(this).data('lightGallery').destroy(true);
          }

          $(this).lightGallery({
              selector: '.item',
              appendSubHtmlTo: ".lg-item",
              addClass: "fb-comments",
              mode: "lg-fade",
              thumbnail:true,
              animateThumb: true,
              showThumbByDefault: true,
              enableDrag: false,
              enableSwipe: false,
              dynamic: true,
              index: $(this).data('gallery-index'),
              dynamicEl: galleryImag
            });        
        });

        $commentBox.on("onAfterSlide.lg", function (event, prevIndex, index) {
          post_id = $("#post_" + index).val();
          user_id = (localStorage.getItem('userId') != '' && localStorage.getItem('userId') != null && localStorage.getItem('userId') != undefined) ? localStorage.getItem('userId') : '';
          
          if (!$(".lg-outer .lg-item").eq(index).attr("data-fb")) {
            try {
              $(".lg-outer .lg-item").eq(index).attr("data-fb", "loaded");

              $.get(environment.apiUrl + 'comments/' + post_id + '/album/' + model_id, {user_type:'MODEL'}, function(data){
                $('.lg-loaded .fb-comments').html('');
                $('.lg-loaded .fb-comments').html(data);
                
                
                  $(".lg-outer.fb-comments .fb-comments").css('background', '#fff no-repeat scroll center center');
                
              });
              // FB.XFBML.parse();
             
            } catch (err) {
              $(window).on("fbAsyncInit", function () {
                $(".lg-outer .lg-item").eq(index).attr("data-fb", "loaded");
                // FB.XFBML.parse();
                console.log('catch block');
              });
            }
          }
        });
    }, 3000);

      
      $('body').on('click', '.s_likeIconFI', function(){

            console.log("component name");

            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: environment.apiUrl + 'postLike/' + post_id + '/album',
            data:'user_id='+user_id+'&user_type=MODEL',
            success:function(data) {
                $('div.lg-current .commentLikeDetails').html('');
              $('div.lg-current .commentLikeDetails').html(data.text);
              $('.likeValue').html('');
              $('.likeValue').html(data.like);
              $('.s_likeIconFI').hide();
              $('.showLikes').css("display", "block");
            }
          })
      });

}
```

Please help in resolving this.
Thanks.

Comment: That's the downside of using `.on('click', xxx)`, you have to remove manually each event listener. You should avoid using jQuery (which leads to this kind of errors). I also see you're using a jQuery ajax call... you are really going too far from Angular... Angular allows you to use `@HostListener` and `(click)="foo()"` things, which automatically remove listeners on destroy for you...

Comment: Thanks @Random, for pointing out, Is there any hacky way to resolve this temporary, Since the lightgallery has been implemented at many component in the app.

Comment: Did you check this? https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/docs/methods/#destroy - lightGallery has a built-in method for destroying its instances.